# Old order email send to admin user Magento 1.9?

Tags: customer, email, order-email

If it is possible to send the old order mail again send to the admin user.

order mail functionality is now working correctly but I have sent old order mail again.

So please anyone tell how to do it in programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code for sending old order to Admin email.

1) Create a new file in your root directory and paste this code.

ini_set("display_errors",1);
define("MAGE_BASE_DIR", "/var/www/magento");
require_once("app/Mage.php");
//require_once MAGE_BASE_DIR . '/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$orderIncrements = range(100000001, 100000002);

foreach ($orderIncrements as $orderIncrement) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrement);

```
if ($order->getId()) {
    try {
        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
        echo "Order $orderIncrement successfully sent\n";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo "Order $orderIncrement not found\n";
}

sleep(2);
```

}

?>

Hope it's work for you.
Thanks

Comment: Hi @mohit you have order range is only 2 but my requirement is 1000+ orders so how can i do it

Comment: HI @Rohit 
yes you can be doing that easily like increase the range as you want.
like  $orderIncrements = range(100000001, 100000102); between range are
increase 100 order email send.

Comment: oh kk good but you have any other reference link to do that this question so please share

Comment: HI @RohitGohel
Yes, I have one link so It's easy to understand for what you want.
 http://www.blog.plazathemes.com/archives/2340